# How to scroll to specific portion of an attributed string

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nsattributedstring

I have an NSMutableAttributedString that lives inside a UIScrollView. I highlight a portion of the string using the [addAttributes:range:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/addAttributes%3arange%3a) function.

When a lot of text is present, I currently have to manually scroll quite a ways to get to the highlighted part. I'd like to come up with a way to have the view automatically scroll to the highlighted portion when the view is loaded - sort of how you can use [anchors to link to a specific part of a webpage](http://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/link-to-specific-line-or-paragraph.shtml).

I'm guessing there is a function that, given some kind of numbers will allow me to scroll to a specific part of my page? How might I come up with such numbers to provide to such a function? Using the NSRange component from the attributed string?

Perhaps there is better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIScrollView` has the method `setContentOffset:animated:` which would allow you to scroll to a particular point in your content.  To figure out what the appropriate offset is, you would have to determine the width of the portion of your attributed string prior to the highlighted part.  The documentation for the methods you use to do this [can be found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).  You could do this using the `size` method of `NSAttributedString`.

It would look something like this:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation SomeViewController {
    UIScrollView* _scrollView;
}

- (void)scrollToOffset:(NSInteger)offset inAttributedString:(NSAttributedString*)attributedString {
    NSAttributedString* attributedSubstring = [attributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, offset)];
    CGFloat width = attributedSubstring.size.width;
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(width, 0.0f) animated:YES];
}
@end
```

The above code assumes that we're talking about a single line of text and that scrolls horizontally.  Alternatively to do this for a fixed width that wraps to an arbitrary height you would need to calculate height with the following code (rather than attributedSubstring.size.height) and then possibly subtract a little to account for wanting to show the last line that of the substring:

```
    CGFloat height = [attributedSubstring boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(<#fixed width to wrap at#>, HUGE_VALF) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil].size.height;
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, height) animated:YES];
```

This is similar to code I use when determining the height of table or collection view cells that have dynamic text that I need to accommodate.

Comment: So that width size is an element of how large the UI component ends up being after all the text (of whatever size and font, etc) is rendered onto the screen?

Comment: @dtmland Yes, the width variable should be the width of the substring when it is rendered, assuming that it is rendered.  It's probably worth noting that I'm assuming you don't have vertical scrolling, just horizontal (which is why the contentOffset value I'm setting has a y value of 0.0f).

Comment: I ended up trying to use the height instead of the width. Strangely, the attributedSubstring.size.height value never appears to take into account when the text lines wrap in the scroll view. I always get the same height no matter what - the only way to affect the height is to adjust the font size.

Comment: Yes, the code above assumes it is going to be displayed on a single line.  I figured we were talking horizontal scrolling.  If you want to determine the height with a wrap point, you'll have to use a different method.  I will update my code above to show this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did not specify it in my original question, but I will address it here. The accepted answer above provides a solution when one wants to scroll horizontally to a specified portion of text. However, in order to scroll vertically a solution similar to that of below is required - other methods may exist but this is what worked for me.

Notice that instead of getting the size component from the attributed sub-string itself, we are getting the size from the view AFTER we've added the sub-string to it. We then insert the full string and force the scroll:

```
NSAttributedString* att_string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mystring];
NSAttributedString* sub_string = [att_string attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, highlight_begin_index)];

[the_view setAttributedText:attributedSubstring];

CGFloat jump_height = the_view.contentSize.height;

[the_view setAttributedText:att_string];
[the_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(the_view.contentOffset.x,jump_height) animated:FALSE];
```

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to account for calculating heights to do the same thing in a vertical scrolling situation.  It doesn't require drawing the string in a view as this solution does..