# NSAttributedString.size - take wrapping into account?

Tags: ios, height, nsattributedstring

Getting the height component via this function:

```
NSAttributedString.size
```

never appears to take into account whether the string wraps inside the view I have it in. It always returns the height of just one line. Perhaps this is intended behavior, but this was misleading as [the documentation states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_7):

> You can use this method prior to drawing to compute how much space is
>   required to draw the string.

Perhaps I simply misunderstand the documentation. Is there any to take into account when the NSAttributedString lines wrap and get a height based on that instead? Perhaps I have to somehow query my view component after I've added the NSAttributedString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this may not be possible. Based on the findings from [one of my other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177726/how-to-scroll-to-specific-portion-of-an-attributed-string/18222812#18222812) I've come to the conclusion that an attributed string cannot have knowledge of how it might wrap in a view *until it has been put into a view*.

This makes sense to me, it is what I was alluding to near the end of my question. If you have different findings please post them and I will likely change the accepted answer.